# Prove that $\mathcal L=\{a^ib^jc^k|i+k=j\}$ is context-free

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

> Prove that $\mathcal L=\{a^ib^jc^k|i+k=j\}$ is context-free

I am trying to prove it without to build a pushdown automaton

First I tried to look which words are in $\mathcal L$,

$\{\varepsilon,ab,bc,abbc,aabb,bbcc,aabbbbcc,\dots\}\in \mathcal L$

---

Here is my start I am stuck couple of hours and don't know how to finish

$$S\to A|\varepsilon\\
A\to aB|B\\
B\to bC|\\
C\to c|\varepsilon$$

Comment: Your start clearly does not work! Maybe start with a grammar for {a^nb^n}

Answer (score 1):

Your current grammar will not work because it only allows for a single $a$ on the left side. You could allow for more $a$'s on the left side with the rule:

$$A \rightarrow aB|aA|B$$

but then we would be allowing an infinite number of $a$'s on the left side.

Here's a hint: $\mathcal{L}$ is the concatenation of two context-free languages.

Comment: With that change, the grammar does not allow an infinite number of $a$s. In fact, in their usual form grammar do not generate any words with infinite length!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: You're right on both counts -- corrected, and I meant "unbounded".